# Postgres Regex issue for different symbols

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to return true if the below line is true but i am getting ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid while executing .

```
var_EmailAddress NOT SIMILAR TO '%( &|,|"|#|:|;|%|$|^|~|!|`|?|<|>|+|=|\|/|*)%'
```

checking any invalid character set in email address.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Try `WHERE var_EmailAddress SIMILAR TO '[^&,"#:;%$^~!\`?<>+=\\/*]+'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape special characters:

```
&|,|"|#|:|;|%|\$|\^|~|!|`|?|<|>|\+|=|\|/|\*
```

Btw it'll be better to use character class probably:

```
[&,"#:;%$^~!`?<>+=\\/*]
```